# Change of state of checkbox on device rotation when using a custom layout twice

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm using a custom layout for date and time picker, **which contains a checkbox**.
This custom layout is used twice in the parent layout.
On changing the device orientation, the checked state of both the checkbox is automatically set to the checked state of the second checkbox.

parent.xml

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:showDividers="beginning">
                ...

                <include
                    layout="@layout/time_picker" />

                <include
                    layout="@layout/time_picker" />
                ...
</LinearLayout>
```

time_picker.xml

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        ...

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/use_date_time_picker"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_extra_small"
            android:checked="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

On changing the device orientation the checked state of the **first** checkbox should retain.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the actual states in two `booleans` in `onSaveInstance` method. Then restore the values in `onRestoreInstance` and set the values to the `checkBox`. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Give id in your layout like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_normal"
    android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="beginning">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/vCb1"
        layout="@layout/time_picker" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/vCb2"
        layout="@layout/time_picker" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now make object like this

```
    View vCb1 =  findViewById(R.id.vCb1);
    View vCb2 =  findViewById(R.id.vCb2);

    CheckBox cb1 =  vCb1.findViewById(R.id.picker);
    CheckBox cb2 =  vCb2.findViewById(R.id.picker);
```

Also put this line in AndroidManifest in  tag

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm using data binding with this, so I can't use ```findViewById()```

Comment: So you can use like that binding.vCb1.picker and binding.vCb2.picker

Comment: I'm sorry. It doesn't help me with anything. Why do I need to create objects like this?

Comment: for differentiate both checkbox.